# CakePHP 4 - How can I prohibit multiple logins?

Tags: authentication, session, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Hi stackoverflow community :),

I built a CakePHP 4 application with a simple login using the Authentication Plugin following the tutorial (https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html). Now I want to prevent one user from being able to log in at the same time. (For safety reasons). I store my session in the database. I cannot set a lock in the user database because the session can also expire without logging out manually.

Does anyone of you have a solution for such a case? How do I check if the user is in the DB as a session? How do I prevent multiple logins for a user?

Comment: It could help to first figure out the boundaries, and the exact meanings of the terms you're using, as there's various ways of solving such problems. Maybe starting with what exactly (from a technical/programming point of view) constitutes multiple logins for your specific application? Generally, one way would be to add a column for the user id to your sessions table, and use an extended session authenticator, which can lookup and modify the sessions table accordingly depending on the authentication status.

Comment: If someone logs in on their computer, then closes their browser without logging in, and visits the site instead from their phone, should they be allowed to log in, or no?

Comment: It's really just to make sure that while someone is logged in, no one else can log in with the same account. This can be done very easily with an entry e.g. logged in=true in the User table, but since the user is automatically logged out after a certain period of inactivity, the column is never emptied. So it's not about browser dependencies, it's just about the fact that a user is really only allowed to log in from a device-independent manner. The session table appears to be browser dependent and creates new sessions per page view and browser.

Comment: Assign a unique identifier to the user when they log in; if you receive a request where the identifier doesn’t match 403/sign the user out. You’ll find this difficult without dealing with js and local storage (to prevent having multiple tabs open, if that’s part of the same concern). Your above comment sounds like you’ll very likely frustrate any user who tries to login and has to wait for their previous login to expire before they can do so…. Why would someone else be logging in as the same user?

Comment: You've missed the point of my question. You are trying to block "someone else" from logging in, but you're entirely likely to end up also blocking the actual person from logging in in perfectly legitimate use cases. IMO, you're not going to add any useful level of security by doing this, but you're going to introduce roadblocks to people using the site as expected. And you're going to spend time writing and maintaining non-standard code to do it.